# Program in C logical operators not working correctly

Tags: c, logic, exit

In the `prompt2` function I have two `if` statements. First `adder` will call `prompt2`. When I press 'x' or 'X', why does it still go to the first 'if' statement, and then it prints, "Answer is..", even though by pressing x, it should've terminated? Essentially I want it to where if you press 'x' or 'X', the program just terminates. Also I'm not in `main` either, so how can I terminate it from a function that isn't `main`? If you need more code, I can edit, just let me know.

```
int prompt2(int sum) {
    char choice; // what the user decides, continuing or not

    printf("\nBefore you continue, take a look at my number guess written down on paper.");
    printf("\nPress 'D' to display the answer or 'X' to exit: " );
    scanf("%c", &choice );

    if ( choice == 'D' || 'd' ) {
        printf("\nAnswer is %d", sum );
    }
    else if ( choice == 'X' || 'x' ) {
        exit(0);

    }


    return 1;

}

int adder( int x, int y ) {

    int sum = 0;

    sum = x + y;
    printf("new sum is %d\n", sum );
    printf(" %d\n+%d\n----\n?", x, y ); // output appropriate line breaks and spacing for equation

    prompt2(sum); // function that asks them if they want to see the answer
    return sum;

}
```

Comment: `if ( choice == 'D' || 'd' )` --> `if ( choice == 'D' || choice == 'd' )`. Same for the `else if`.

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much, I can't believe I didn't catch that.

Answer (score 4):

In the statement `if ( choice == 'D' || 'd' )` the `d` is not equal to zero and therefore evaluates to `true`. It should be `if ( choice == 'D' || choice == 'd' )` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As example, you must change this line: `if ( choice == 'D' || 'd' )` with `if ( choice == 'D' || choice == 'd' )`.
The variable must be rewritten after each || or && statement.